# how can i create a file folder in a repository on GitHub?

Tags: github, repository

how can i create a file folder in a repository on GitHub? at the moment I am putting all my exercises in different repository. I hope to explained well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create an empty folder in GitHub, so you have to create a file inside the folder for this.

In you repository, if you click in "Add File", and then in "Create new File", you can set the name of the folder, followed by the name of a dummy file. Something like this:

```
folder/file.txt
```

Once you have created this dummy file, a folder is created with it, and now you can upload your exercises and delete the dummy file. (Don't delete the dummy file before uploading another file because the folder will dissapear).

A better option is using git for creating a local repository with your folder structure and pushing it.